# Reaching a certain data with the navigation view in a SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I make a navigation view and then I want to get some data from the list that it defines as Rosette. But I could not. I will be grateful if you could help me.
My code is like this:

```
struct UserProfileResponse {
    let userName : String
    let level : Int
    let photo : String
    let followerCount : Int
    let followCount : Int
    let name : String
    let title : String
    let bio : String
    let height : Float
    let weight : Float
    let dateOfBirth : Int
    let rosette : [Rosette]
    let activities : [ActivityModel]
    let docId : String
}
```

Rosette is like this:

```
struct Rosette {
    let sıra: Int
    let rosetteImage : String
    let goldStep : Int
    let rosetteName : String
    let rosetteLevel : Int
    let rosetteDone : Int
    let percentageComplete : Double
    var shouldShowTitle:Bool{
        percentageComplete <= 1
    }
}
struct CircleLevelList {
    static let four = [
        Rosette(sıra: 1, rosetteImage: "Football", goldStep: 25, rosetteName: "Football Star", rosetteLevel: 12, rosetteDone: 12, percentageComplete: 1),
        Rosette(sıra: 2, rosetteImage: "voleybol", goldStep: 25 ,rosetteName: "Voleybol Star", rosetteLevel: 16, rosetteDone: 8, percentageComplete: 0.50),
        Rosette(sıra: 3, rosetteImage: "Tabletennis", goldStep: 25, rosetteName: "Tabletennis Star", rosetteLevel: 12, rosetteDone: 4, percentageComplete: 0.33),
        Rosette(sıra: 4, rosetteImage: "Basketball", goldStep: 25, rosetteName: "Basketball Star", rosetteLevel: 10, rosetteDone: 1, percentageComplete: 1)
     ]
}
```

While accessing all the information in the UserProfile Response on the detail screen, I also want to see the rosetteLevel and rosetteDone data inside the Rosette on the detail screen. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: See: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html
In particular how to use arrays. Hint, `userProfileResponse.rosette[0].rosetteLevel`

Comment: You should share your view code.